# Как определить число букв в массиве?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "rus");
    int f = 0; // f - это количство пробелов в слове
    int s = 10; // s - это количество букв в слове (изначально 10)
    char tt[10];
    cin >> tt;
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (tt[i] == ' ') f++;
    }
    s = s - f;
    cout << s << endl;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Здравствуйте, у меня такая проблема. Мне нужно узнать число букв в массиве. Я пытался сначала найти число пробелов после слова, а потом вычесть его из количества символом максимально возможного массива. У меня выходит число пробелов = 0. Как сделать так, что бы выводило число букв в массиве?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема усложняется тем, что строка может содержать символы unicode. буквы кириллицы, например. Чтобы их подсчитать, нужно определить длину символа по первому байту.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;


// Определяем длину символа UTF-8
int u8_char_len(char first_byte) {
    unsigned short int bytes = 0;
    if ((first_byte & 0xC0) == 0xC0) {
        if ((first_byte & 0xF0) == 0xF0) bytes = 4;
        else if ((first_byte & 0xE0) == 0xE0) bytes = 3;
        else bytes = 2;
    } else bytes = 1;
    return bytes;
}


// Определяем длину строки UTF-8
int u8_str_len(char * str) {
    int i = 0, count = 0;
    for (; str[i] != '\0'; i += u8_char_len(str[i]))
        if (str[i] != ' ')
            count++;
    return count;
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "rus");
    char tt[10];
    cin.getline(tt, 10);
    int symbols_count = u8_str_len(tt);
    cout << symbols_count << endl;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Не могу понять, как правильно некоторые разработчики используют `hexidecimal` ссылке в коде. В универе как-то прошло мимо меня. Можете объяснить почему вы решили здесь использовать именно эти `0xC0` значения и остальные? Как показывает онлайн конвертер `0xC0 = 192`. Какая связь с первым байтом?

Comment: @raviga, система счисления не важна.
(first_byte & 0xC0) == 0xC0) показывает нам, что два старших бита в первом байте установлены в 1. Это, в свою очередь, говорит о том, что символ содержит как минимум 2 байта.
Если это не так и first_byte & 192 оказывается не равен 192, то мы возвращаем 1 (символ состоит из одного байта).
Если так, то проверяем сначала 240 (не установлены ли 4 старшие бита). Потом 224 - три старших бита.

Так кодируется utf8:
0xxxxxxx - символ из одного байта;
110xxxxx 10xxxxxx - символ из двух байт и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

Считывание через `>>` в массив символов (да и в `std::string` тоже) идет до первого пробела.

Если вам нужна вся строка (со всеми пробелами, до символа переноса строки), используйте `std::getline` (и заодно замените массив символов на более удобный `std::string`):

```
std::string tt;
std::getline(std::cin, tt);
```

---

Кроме того, чтобы не считать символы вручную, можно использовать `std::count` и `std::count_if`:

```
число_пробелов = std::count(tt.begin(), tt.end(), ' ');
число_букв = std::count_if(tt.begin(), tt.end(), [](unsigned char c){return std::isalpha(c);});
```

Еще, пробелы можно считать через:

```
число_пробелов = std::count_if(tt.begin(), tt.end(), [](unsigned char c){return std::isspace(c);});
```

Тогда будут подсчитаны все "пробельные символы", куда кроме пробела входит табуляция и еще кое-что.